# Turn acausal Butterworth output into output of a causal Butterworth without input signal

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, bandpass

I have a dataset which contains a large number of time-series which have been filtered with acausal Butterworth filters. For a real-time application, I can only use causally filtered data.
Is it possible to turn the output of an acausal Butterworth filter into what would have been obtained if the original time-series had been run through a causal Butterworth filter?
(I do not have the original, unfiltered, time-series)

I do know the order of the filter that was applied, the corner freuquencies, and some parameter 'nroll' of which I don't know what it is ... (nroll is usually equal 2.5)

Comment: You mean that you want to keep the frequency response identical, but shift the phase so that it is equal to the output of a minimal-phase filter?

Comment: yes, that's exactly my goal

Comment: Do you know the order and cutoff of the filters that were used?

Comment: Not sure if you mean corner frequencies with 'cutoff'?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  Do you know the properties of the filters that were used?

Comment: Yes, I know corner frequencies and order (see modified question above)

Comment: Hmmm.. acausal filter implies you've run the signal through the same filter twice, once forwards and once backwards, right, like matlab's `filtfilt()`?  So a 1st-order filter would produce a 2nd-order frequency response?  In that case, I think you could use an allpass filter with the same poles as your original filter.  The corresponding zeros cancel out the frequency response while doubling the phase response to produce the same phase response as the 2nd order filter would have had, had it been causal/minimum-phase.

Comment: `nroll` is apparently just half the filter order.  One reference says "The basic parameter in the Converse and Brady (1992) BAP filter routines, used in my record processing software, is *nroll*, where *nroll* ≡ 0.5 *p*. This in itself is confusing (why not use *p*?)."

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, as long as you know the filter which was applied to the data in the first place.

Assuming that the original acausal filter is $H_a(\omega)$ and your filtered data is $Y_a(\omega)$, then the original data $X(\omega)$ can be retrieved by inversely applying the filter to the data:
\begin{equation}
X(\omega) = \frac{Y_a(\omega)}{H_a(\omega)}
\end{equation}

This is simply a re-arrangement of the equation which can be used to describe the initial  filtering operation:
\begin{equation}
Y_a(\omega) = X(\omega) H_a(\omega)
\end{equation}

I've illustrated the concept using frequency domain notation, but the concept is the same for the time domain.  Depending upon your acausal filter, you may encounter some problems inverting it, I don't think this will be an issue in this case.